# How to use 'grep' to match a string except when another string matches?

Tags: bash, grep

In the following file I just looking for a grep command:

```
Line 1 : string 1  (errno:1)
Line 2 : string 1  (errno:3)
Line 3 : string 1  (errno:1)
Line 4 : string 1  (errno:1)
```

It should match "string 1" and not equal to "errno:1". How can I do that using grep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there's a way of doing it all together, but the easiest way is just to chain multiple grep commands together

```
cat <myfile> | grep "string 1" | grep -v "errno:1"
```

The `-v` option inverts the search, so that will display the lines that have "string 1" without "errno:1"

Comment: UUOC aka useless use of cat.  Just start off with `grep "string1" <myfile>`

Answer (score 3):

Find any "string 1" that is not followed by "errno:1":

```
grep -P 'string 1(?!.*errno:1)' inputfile
```

Comment: @codeaddict: Probably not. I should have mentioned that it's GNU `grep`.

Comment: It's also available in OS X `grep`.

Comment: In MinGW (standard installation), *-P* is not available: *"grep: Support for the -P option is not compiled into this --disable-perl-regexp binary"*.